# Twitter Bootstrap Modal button options to specify when triggering via javascript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In order to trigger opening of a Twitter Bootstrap modal, I have a button and I have a Jquery Java Script function on click event of the button.

Q1) 
In JS function, if I specify 
$("#mymodal").modal('show');

Do I still need to specify data-toggle="modal" as one of the attributes in the button element?

Q2) Do I need to specify $("#mymodal").modal('toggle') in my JS function prior to $("#mymodal").modal('show')?

Q3) Do I need to specify $("#mymodal").modal('toggle') alone in my JS function and no $("#mymodal").modal('show')?

Q4) How does show and toggle differ in this context, when I trigger the opening via JS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions..

Q1) No. You only need to use attributes or javascript, but not both.

Q2) No, just 'show' will display the modal.

Q3 / Q4) It depends on the functionality you want from the button. If 'show' is used, subsequent clicks on the button will have no effect. If 'toggle' is used, a subsequent click on the button will close the modal.

Toggle will close the modal when it's open, and open the modal when it's closed. It provides both `show` and `hide`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://bootply.com/62174)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Skelly, that precisely answers my questions and clarifies my doubts. Thanks for the demo as well. However, when a modal is open, how can I click on the button, which triggered it? I believe, only if we use data-backdrop="false", we can do that. Correct me if I am wrong.